# Is it possible to detect if the device has Hotspot enable?

Tags: react-native, hotspot, react-native-community-netinfo

I have to find if the device where my application run, has the Wi-Fi enable or if the device is in hotspot mode, else I want to display an error message.

To detect if I am connected to Wi-Fi, I'm using @react-native-community/netinfo, but I can't find anything about the hotspot for react native.

The only things I want are to know if the hotspot is enabled on my device (and, if possible, if there are devices connected to this hotspot).

Thank you for your help.